# How to use external terminal in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am switching from atom to vs code and I want to run python and c++ files in external terminal. The only extension in vs code is code runner and it doesn't support executing the code in an external terminal. I think it's possible to do that with tasks 2.0.0 but I was not able to get one from stack overflow that works and they need to be configured for each folder separately. Isn't there any extension in vs code like [atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run) and [gcc-make-run](https://atom.io/packages/gcc-make-run) so that you press a button and it executes your code with whatever flags you put in the extension settings in an external terminal window.